# Can enums be part of two stages?

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum of status of products, it contains 5 status, I need 2 enums to be at stage one and the others 3 in stage two, is this possible? how?

I tried with doing another class and extends from the enum but thats not possible since enums are finals

```
public enum StatusEnum {
 NEW,PROCESS,COOKING, DELIVERED, CANCELLED
}

if (Product p instance of StageOne){
   p.setStatusEnum(COOKING);
} else {
   throw new Exception("e");
}
```

I need this since you could cancel the product if the status enum is only in stage one

Comment: Sounds like the stages are status as well, no? What is the purpose of the stages? I really doubt, that I understand your queston.

Comment: @triplem it makes sense to have some sort of grouping for the status types. For example `NEW` and `PROCESS` may be part of stage 1, `COOKING` part of stage 2 and so on...

Answer (score 5):

Enums can have fields and method just like regular classes (but it's usually a very good idea to make sure that they are immutable, i.e. none of the fields can change after creation):

```
public enum StatusStage {
  STAGE1,
  STAGE2
}

public enum StatusEnum
  NEW(StatusStage.STAGE1),
  PROCESS(StatusStage.STAGE1),
  COOKING(StatusStage.STAGE1),
  DELIVERED(StatusStage.STAGE2),
  CANCELLED(StatusStage.STAGE2);

  public final StatusStage stage;

  private StatusEnum(final StatusStage stage) {
    this.stage = stage;
  }
}
```

You could even add methods like this:

```
public boolean canFrobnicate() {
  return this.stage != StatusStage.STAGE2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as nice as the answer by Joachim, but a simple other method easily adaptable :

```
public enum StatusEnum {

    NEW,PROCESS,COOKING, DELIVERED, CANCELLED;


    public boolean isFromStage(int stage){

        switch(stage){

            case 1 :
                return this == NEW || this == PROCESS;
            case 2 :
                return this == COOKING || this == DELIVERED || this == CANCELLED;
            default :
                return false;


        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Joachim Summer is what is recommended to do but i can propose this

```
public enum StatusEnum {
 NEW,PROCESS,COOKING, DELIVERED, CANCELLED;

static List<StatusEnum> stageOne(){
   return Arrays.asList(NEW, PROCESS);
}
static List<StatusEnum> stageTwo(){
   return Arrays.asList(COOKING, DELIVERED, CANCELLED);
}
```